# "Unequivocably" vs. "unequivocally"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, suffixes

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in a news article titled “SCIENCE WATCH; PROGRESS IN AIDS DISPUTE” in The New York Times (March 10, 1987).

> Dr. Robert Gallo at the cancer institute later isolated the same virus and asserts that his laboratory first demonstrated **unequivocably** the role of the virus in causing AIDS.

After [searching on Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/?region=us&q=unequivocably), I have found no item for "unequivocably", but I got a lot of hits (139.000) from Google; so I am wondering if "unequivocably" is in common usage nowadays.

Can someone clarify this question? Or is "unequivocably" a common error?

Comment: As you said, Google search on unequivocably shows
about 139,000 results but below that it says "Did you mean: unequivocally" and searching "unequivocally" shows about 8,880,000 results.

Comment: What Wishwas said. This is General Reference.

Comment: I searched for and came across this question after watching an episode of the TV show "Crusade" called "The Well Of Forever" in which one of the characters says "unequivocably" but in the DVD subtitles it says "unequivocally". Interesting that the subtitles are actually more correct than the actual show on this occasion.

Answer (score 5):

The correct word is *unequivocally*. *Unequivocably* is wrong.

According to Merriam-Webster, *unequivocably* is a non-standard word for *unequivocally*. Its first known use was in 1917.

The word (*unequivocally*) was perhaps altered by drawing an analogy between *unequivocal* and, say, *understand*. *Understand* changes to *understandably*, so they changed *unequivocal* to *unequivocably*. Though, as I said, it's wrong.

Comment: If it's so commonly used, should it still be wrong? English is constantly evolving, let's add another change.

Comment: I came here to figure out if these two words have subtly different meanings or if they are synonyms. My first instinct was actually that `-bly` was the proper term because it flows through my mouth somewhat more fluidly. What a surprise.